# Hochschild-Serre for étale cohomology vs. Galois cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be an irreducible smooth projective variety of dimension d over a number field K. Let $\bar X$ denote its base change to an algebraic closure of K. Then, if Understand it right, the Hochschil-Serre spectral sequence can be used to prove that for any $i\geq 1$ and any integer $m$, there is an isomorphism

$$
H^i_{et}(X,Z_p(m)) = H^1(G_K,H_{et}^{i-1}(\bar X,Z_p(m)))
$$

Since I know very little about spectral sequences, I am confused about some consequences one could derive from such isomorphism.

For instance take $d=1$, $i=1$, $m=0$, so $X$ is a curve. Then

$$
H^1_{et}(X,Z_p) = H^1(G_K,H_{et}^{0}(\bar X,Z_p))
$$

The left-hand side is a very rich object, sitting in an exact sequence which shows that it is an extension of $H_{et}^1(\bar X,Z_p)$ and $G_K \otimes Z_p$. The right-hand side looks rather trivial because 
$H_{et}^{0}(\bar X,Z_p) = Z_p$ and hence  $H^1(G_K,H_{et}^{0}(\bar X,Z_p)) = Hom(G_K, Z_p) = (G_K \otimes Z_p)^*$.

There is something that I'm obviously doing wrong, because the way I put it, the left-hand side is far from isomorphic to the right-hand side.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the HLSSS does not imply the statement you refer to, but that $H^1_{ét}(X;\mathbb{Z}_p(n))$ is an extension of $H^0(G_K;H^1(\bar X;\mathbb{Z}_p))$ by $H^1(G_K;H^0(\bar X;\mathbb{Z}_p))$

Comment: Yes, this is what makes sense. In other words, what I'm asking is: if the arrow I claimed exists, but fails to be an isomorphism, what is for every case the kernel and cokernel?

Comment: In general the SS tells you only that there is a filtration of $H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}_p(m))$ whose associated graded is a subquotient of $\bigoplus_j H^j(G_F;H^{i-j}(\bar X;\mathbb{Z}_p))$, in a way compatible with the canonical map $H^i(X;\mathbb{Z}_p(m))\to H^i(\bar X;\mathbb{Z}_p)^{G_F}\cong H^0(G_F;H^i(\bar X;\mathbb{Z}_p))$. In special situations you can extract more informations, but not in the generality you set in the question. Would this be enough for an answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot Denis. This is indeed helpful, and I appreciate it. But I would like to hear a more accurate answer allowing me to compute the output in many examples. I also wouls like to see stated a corollary asserting that, under explicit hypothesis, one does have the isomorphism I claimed (according to the literature, such arrow is indeed an isomorphism in many cases)

Comment: For any $i \neq 2m$, $H^0( G_F, H^i ( \overline{x} , \mathbb Z_p(m))$ vanishes for reasons of weights. Probably one can prove some vanishing for higher $i$ as well using duality properties of Galois cohomology. But where in the literature is this isomorphism claimed?

Comment: I was looking at section 10.3 of the paper by Loeffler, Skinner and Zerbes on GSp(4). But this is a very particular case. For a more general reference, look at Nekovar's "p-adic Abel-Jacobi maps and p-adic heights", sections 1.1 and 1.2. There I just realized that you are right: in general the isomorphism is only true when the left-hand side is taken to be the first graded piece (j=1 in Nekovar's notation). How can we compute this graded quotient, just to know what is this?

Comment: "I was looking at section 10.3 of the paper by Loeffler, Skinner and Zerbes on GSp(4)" -- I fear you may have misunderstood, since throughout this section we localise at a (rather carefully chosen) ideal $I$ of the spherical Hecke algebra, whose function (among other things) is to kill all the cohomology of $\overline{X}$ outside the middle degree. It is clearly not true that $H^i(X) = H^1(K, H^{i-1}(\overline{X}))$ in general.